# Adding image to database php and html

Tags: php, html

so i have this bit of code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO series (ID, Name, Details, Seasons, Price, Image)
VALUES
('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Details]','$_POST[Seasons]','$_POST[Price]','$_POST[Image]')";
```

and i want to somehow force the img tang inside the $_POST[image] so when it is shown in html, it will show the picture, not the link.
Is this possible?

something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO series (ID, Name, Details, Seasons, Price, Image)
VALUES
('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Details]','$_POST[Seasons]','$_POST[Price]','"<img src="$_POST[Image]">"')";
```

Comment: Your query is ready to get injected!!

Comment: i know, this is for fun... nothing serious

Comment: Not funny from the developers point of view. This is irresponsible even if it is for **fun**

Comment: The answer is a bit more complicated. Have a look at the reference manual about file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all save image name into database then use src tag to show image into html.

```
$sqlimage  = "SELECT image FROM series where `id` = $id1";
$imageresult1 = mysql_query($sqlimage);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
{
    $image = $rows['Image'];
    echo "<img src='$image' >";
    echo "<br>";
}
```